# NoMethodError: undefined method `update_average_rating' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rail application with 3 models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews

end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :movie
belongs_to :user
after_create :update_movie_rating
  def update_movie_rating
    movie.update_average_rating
  end
end
```

I'm trying to update the average rating of movie after creating each reviews.

Here is the methods I use in movie model.

```
def update_average_rating(review=nil)
  s = self.reviews.sum(:rating)
  c = self.reviews.count
  self.update_attribute(:average_rating, c == 0 ? 0.0 : s / c.to_f)
end
```

This method is using with `after_create` callback in the review model.

But I get error like this when I deploy to heroku. I can't make `post` to the the application which is deployed on heroku. What will be the reason behind it?
I get it right while trying to update it with admin panel (active admin).

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_average_rating' for nil:NilClass):
2015-06-08T20:09:06.297312+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/review.rb:6:in `update_movie_rating'
2015-06-08T20:09:06.297314+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:36:in `block in create'
2015-06-08T20:09:06.297315+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:35:in `create'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: show the the code here `app/models/review.rb:6:in `update_meal_rating'`....

Comment: @ArupRakshit updated the question with code.

Comment: `movie` is not set. It is `nil`, which is indicated by the error message. You should ensure that Reviews cannot be saved or created without a Movie.